# Kill all processes with certain name after given time

Tags: linux, centos, kill

I am trying to kill all processes that have name 'reg.php' that are older than 60min.

I do something similar to remove orphaned cookie files
find /cookies/ -type f -mmin +60 -delete

So basically like that but to kill the orphaned processes.

Would love and appreciate any help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
killall --older-than 1h reg.php
```

If you're dealing with “zombies”, use `-9`

```
killall -9 --older-than 1h reg.php
```

But be aware that in this case, the programm cannot properly shut down.

Or combine both methods:

```
killall --older-than 1h reg.php ; sleep 2 ; killall -9 --older-than 1h reg.php
```

This would first send the termination signal to the “alive” processes, give them 2 seconds to shut down, then kill the zombies.

Comment: On what OS/version are you? What version of killall (`killall -V`) do you use?

Comment: killall (PSmisc) 22.6 | CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

Comment: Does your `man killall` mention `--older-than`? I thought this was not such a new feature. Also, did you change the command line provided in the answer? Maybe forget to include the script name?

Comment: Wow, apparently CentOS ships a 7 year old `psmisc` package: http://psmisc.sourceforge.net/changelog.html